# RxAndroid: Merge multiple calls

Tags: android, rx-android

I'm starting on Rx with RxAndroid and want to get list the images by it's API with Retrofit.

Retrofit interface:

```
public interface ImageApi {

    @GET("image")
    Observable<ImageDto> getImage(@Query("id") final Integer id);
}
```

Here I get one object:

```
public void getImage(final Integer id, final Observer<ImageDto> observer) {
    imageApi.getImage(id)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
}
```

And method to get list images is more complicated then I thought. In that case got List with one element:

```
public void getImages(final List<Integer> ids, final Observer<List<ImageDto>> observer) {
    Observable.from(ids).flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<ImageDto>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<ImageDto> call(Integer id) {
            return imageApi.getImage(id);
        }
}).toList().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(observer);
```

Understand that i should use:

```
Observable.zip
```

but I can`t realize how. Could someone help me?

Comment: Zip is more geared towards sequential requests. It looks like you're on the right track. Can you verify that the nested getImage call is called once per image id?

Comment: You're right, code is correct. Sometimes because of my mistake i got only one id in list. Thank you anyway.
Is there a way to make the nested call less?

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct. I've made a mistake and got only one id in list.
Resolved.